# Alienware m17x r2 not booting up

Tags: bios, firmware, post, flashing

My believe my BIOS is bricked. I was flashing my BIOS and power was interrupted. It never went off when power was interrupted. And being a novice, I tried to forcefully power it down still nothing happened. So I removed my batteries.

The laptop has not booted up since then. I ve tried all I can

1. reset the BIOS.
2. Blind flashing with a bootable pendrive (would using the cd rom be better?)
3. Tried re-seating rams, and GPUs.

Nothing has worked still.

On powering on, the system comes on. Fans pick up and slow down to almost being quiet. Power buttons (small alien head) lights up, keyboard backlight, track pad lights up, scroll lock LED continuously flash, CAPS lock LED stays on (no flashing like the other two). CDROM seem to run the CD stuck inside ita alot (it magically came out though yesterday).

What can I do to rectify issue?

Comment: Can you access the CMOS battery? If so, pull that out for a minute or two, replace it, and try booting again.

Comment: Removing the battery would just reset the stored configuration? The OP mentioned that this was already done. (bullet point #1, though it is now more visible with the markup fixed).

Comment: Thanks a lot Hennes. I see your edits. I do appreciate. I actually decided to disassemble the laptop. From dell support i found some boot error codes. The LED lights that had been blinking (and that which had no been booting) indicates LCD failure or board. Surprisingly, the larger LCD cable was not seating properly so I set that in other. No more LED flashes, still system would not start so I began swapping or removing hardware and trying to boot again. Discovered that one RAM our of two is bad. There is still another set of LED flashes.Still not editing